# How to find the positions of the max and min numbers in the array?

Tags: c, arrays, position, max, min

```
int A[5] = {2, 2, 1, 4, 1};    
int max = A[0], min = A[0];
int k,l;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (A[i] >= max) {
        max = A[i];
        k = i;
    }
}

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if (A[j] <= min) {
        min = A[j];
        l = j;
    }
}

printf("densely is: %d ", k);
printf("\n");
printf("loosely is: %d ", l);
```

Program prints position of `densely` (`max`) as `3`.
It prints out position of `loosely` (`min`) as `4`.
But the correct answer for the `loosely` (`min`) position should be `2` and `4`.
In my case, the `max` number is `4`, so the position should be `3`(counted from `0`).
The `min` number is `1`, so the position should be `2` and `4`.
Now, my code only shows one position for the `min` number: `4`.
It should print both positions: `2` and `4`.

I want to print out all positions for the `max` and `min` numbers.

Comment: Why do you think that? The code is looking for the last occurrence of maximum and minimum. Maximum is 4, minimum is 1. Last occurrences is at index 4(min) and index 3(max).

Comment: Do you expect the first occurrence? Then try `>` instead of `>=` and `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: I want to print out the all position of the max and min number. 
In this case the max number is 4,so the position should be 3(count from 0). 
The min number is 1,so the position should be 2 and 4. 
Now my code only shows the min number position is 4. 
What i want is that it shows 2 and 4

Comment: That really helps understanding your question. I recommend to explain that, in your question. Use [edit] to do that. It would also help to avoid the confusion introduced by the words "loosely" and "densley". Either by avoiding those words, or by explaining them.

Comment: Basically you want to output potentially more than one information on maximum indexes and more than one information on minimum indexes. Did you consider using more than one variable for storing those? You might need to use as many variables for both cases as there are members in your array, because all array members can contai the maximum value and the minimum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very good question. The key to the solution is to find the `min` and `max` value in the array `A`.  That part has been done and works well. The only improvement here is to start from index `1` and remove `=` from `>=` and `<=` comparisons.
The missing part is to remember all indexes for `min` and `max`.

That is difficult to do in one pass. What you can do in one pass is to find both `min` and `max`.

Once you have `min` and `max` in  the second pass you could mark all the index positions for `max` and `min` in additional index tables called `maximums`and `minimums`. (Since I want to print those values I have two separate loops for it.)

The solution is quite simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Find all minimums and all maximums in the array A
// Find and remember where `max` and `min` values were in the array A
// The algorithm is symmetrical for minimum and maximum 

int main(void)
{             // 0  1  2  3  4 
    int A[5] = { 2, 2, 1, 4, 1};    

    int maximums[5] = {0};  // we keep max positions here
    int minimums[5] = {0};  // we keep min positions here

    int max = A[0];  // we assume max at index 0
    int min = A[0];  // we assume min at index 0

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {       // we can start from index 1 because of the above assumption
        if (A[i] > max) max = A[i];     // densely 
        if (A[i] < min) min = A[i];     // loosely
    }

    // Find the all elements equal to `max` and `min` 
    // and register them in `maximums` and `minimums` arrays

    // Print the results:
    printf("max value is: %d and it occurs at the following index(es):\n", max);         
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        if (A[i] == max){ 
            maximums[i] = 1;   // mark this index as maximum being here
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }

    printf("\nmin value is: %d and it occurs at the following index(es):\n", min );   
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        if (A[i] == min){ 
            minimums[i] = 1;   // mark this index as minimum being here
            printf("%d ", i);
        }    
    }

    // At this moment we not only printed the results 
    // but the array minimums and maximums remember where the `min` and `max` were.

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
max value is: 4 and it occurs at the following index(es):                                                                                       
3                                                                                                                                               
min value is: 1 and it occurs at the following index(es):                                                                                       
2 4
```

Comment: Thank you. That's really help a lot